# ICP to trajectory estimation, transformation matrix different than groundtruth (point clouds)

Tags: python, matrix, point-clouds, closest-points, kitti

I have this ground-truth trajectory, which is an array with 30 homogeneous coordinates transformation matrix that are 30 positions of a car.

```
[[[ 1.000000e+00  9.043680e-12  2.326809e-11  5.551115e-17]
  [ 9.043683e-12  1.000000e+00  2.392370e-10  3.330669e-16]
  [ 2.326810e-11  2.392370e-10  9.999999e-01 -4.440892e-16]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.999978e-01  5.272628e-04 -2.066935e-03 -4.690294e-02]
  [-5.296506e-04  9.999992e-01 -1.154865e-03 -2.839928e-02]
  [ 2.066324e-03  1.155958e-03  9.999971e-01  8.586941e-01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.999910e-01  1.048972e-03 -4.131348e-03 -9.374345e-02]
  [-1.058514e-03  9.999968e-01 -2.308104e-03 -5.676064e-02]
  [ 4.128913e-03  2.312456e-03  9.999887e-01  1.716275e+00]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.999796e-01  1.566466e-03 -6.198571e-03 -1.406429e-01]
  [-1.587952e-03  9.999927e-01 -3.462706e-03 -8.515762e-02]
  [ 6.193102e-03  3.472479e-03  9.999747e-01  2.574964e+00]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.999637e-01  2.078471e-03 -8.263498e-03 -1.874858e-01]
  [-2.116664e-03  9.999871e-01 -4.615826e-03 -1.135202e-01]
  [ 8.253797e-03  4.633149e-03  9.999551e-01  3.432648e+00]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.999433e-01  2.586172e-03 -1.033094e-02 -2.343818e-01]
  [-2.645881e-03  9.999798e-01 -5.770163e-03 -1.419150e-01]
  [ 1.031581e-02  5.797170e-03  9.999299e-01  4.291335e+00]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.999184e-01  3.088363e-03 -1.239599e-02 -2.812195e-01]
  [-3.174350e-03  9.999710e-01 -6.922975e-03 -1.702743e-01]
  [ 1.237425e-02  6.961759e-03  9.998991e-01  5.148987e+00]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.998890e-01  3.586305e-03 -1.446384e-02 -3.281178e-01]
  [-3.703403e-03  9.999605e-01 -8.077186e-03 -1.986703e-01]
  [ 1.443430e-02  8.129853e-03  9.998627e-01  6.007777e+00]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.998551e-01  4.078705e-03 -1.652913e-02 -3.749547e-01]
  [-4.231669e-03  9.999484e-01 -9.229794e-03 -2.270290e-01]
  [ 1.649063e-02  9.298401e-03  9.998207e-01  6.865477e+00]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.998167e-01  4.566671e-03 -1.859652e-02 -4.218367e-01]
  [-4.760342e-03  9.999347e-01 -1.038342e-02 -2.554151e-01]
  [ 1.854788e-02  1.047004e-02  9.997731e-01  7.724036e+00]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.997738e-01  5.049868e-03 -2.066463e-02 -4.687329e-01]
  [-5.289072e-03  9.999194e-01 -1.153730e-02 -2.838096e-01]
  [ 2.060470e-02  1.164399e-02  9.997198e-01  8.582886e+00]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.997264e-01  5.527315e-03 -2.272922e-02 -5.155474e-01]
  [-5.816781e-03  9.999025e-01 -1.268908e-02 -3.121547e-01]
  [ 2.265686e-02  1.281782e-02  9.996611e-01  9.440275e+00]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.996745e-01  6.000540e-03 -2.479692e-02 -5.624310e-01]
  [-6.345160e-03  9.998840e-01 -1.384246e-02 -3.405416e-01]
  [ 2.471098e-02  1.399530e-02  9.995966e-01  1.029896e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.996182e-01  6.468772e-03 -2.686440e-02 -6.093087e-01]
  [-6.873365e-03  9.998639e-01 -1.499561e-02 -3.689250e-01]
  [ 2.676374e-02  1.517453e-02  9.995266e-01  1.115757e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.995562e-01  7.058450e-03 -2.894213e-02 -6.562052e-01]
  [-7.530449e-03  9.998399e-01 -1.623192e-02 -3.973964e-01]
  [ 2.882292e-02  1.644266e-02  9.994492e-01  1.201541e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.995095e-01  5.595311e-03 -3.081450e-02 -7.018788e-01]
  [-6.093682e-03  9.998517e-01 -1.610315e-02 -4.239119e-01]
  [ 3.071983e-02  1.628303e-02  9.993953e-01  1.286965e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.994226e-01  7.842768e-03 -3.306167e-02 -7.498241e-01]
  [-8.456089e-03  9.997940e-01 -1.845198e-02 -4.540039e-01]
  [ 3.291014e-02  1.872089e-02  9.992829e-01  1.373146e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.993587e-01  8.704386e-03 -3.473400e-02 -7.992511e-01]
  [-9.439421e-03  9.997338e-01 -2.105422e-02 -4.840770e-01]
  [ 3.454149e-02  2.136859e-02  9.991747e-01  1.460026e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.992482e-01  1.235688e-02 -3.674849e-02 -8.546642e-01]
  [-1.320676e-02  9.996488e-01 -2.297477e-02 -5.155070e-01]
  [ 3.645169e-02  2.344282e-02  9.990604e-01  1.547957e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.991826e-01  1.352279e-02 -3.809783e-02 -9.072868e-01]
  [-1.439161e-02  9.996404e-01 -2.262373e-02 -5.464705e-01]
  [ 3.777819e-02  2.315352e-02  9.990178e-01  1.636940e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.991241e-01  1.328777e-02 -3.967996e-02 -9.609163e-01]
  [-1.412604e-02  9.996813e-01 -2.092052e-02 -5.783595e-01]
  [ 3.938933e-02  2.146271e-02  9.989934e-01  1.726896e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.990604e-01  1.351433e-02 -4.118029e-02 -1.011589e+00]
  [-1.432436e-02  9.997084e-01 -1.943894e-02 -6.092403e-01]
  [ 4.090558e-02  2.001055e-02  9.989626e-01  1.817318e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.990174e-01  1.304822e-02 -4.235654e-02 -1.066256e+00]
  [-1.386115e-02  9.997242e-01 -1.895579e-02 -6.387363e-01]
  [ 4.209752e-02  1.952427e-02  9.989227e-01  1.908411e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.989383e-01  1.325999e-02 -4.411963e-02 -1.118651e+00]
  [-1.413494e-02  9.997084e-01 -1.957870e-02 -6.686219e-01]
  [ 4.384715e-02  2.018154e-02  9.988343e-01  1.999722e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.989120e-01  1.152857e-02 -4.518863e-02 -1.171840e+00]
  [-1.247777e-02  9.997062e-01 -2.077977e-02 -6.990778e-01]
  [ 4.493579e-02  2.132101e-02  9.987623e-01  2.091368e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.988800e-01  1.128892e-02 -4.595003e-02 -1.224279e+00]
  [-1.218132e-02  9.997417e-01 -1.918760e-02 -7.287421e-01]
  [ 4.572155e-02  1.972584e-02  9.987594e-01  2.184042e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.988593e-01  1.299421e-02 -4.594914e-02 -1.280807e+00]
  [-1.370812e-02  9.997896e-01 -1.525610e-02 -7.604717e-01]
  [ 4.574123e-02  1.586857e-02  9.988272e-01  2.277432e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.988876e-01  1.379030e-02 -4.509495e-02 -1.334841e+00]
  [-1.432558e-02  9.998304e-01 -1.156850e-02 -7.929673e-01]
  [ 4.492776e-02  1.220164e-02  9.989157e-01  2.370953e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.989649e-01  1.285173e-02 -4.363580e-02 -1.385747e+00]
  [-1.325687e-02  9.998715e-01 -9.007757e-03 -8.209244e-01]
  [ 4.351442e-02  9.576906e-03  9.990068e-01  2.465175e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.990298e-01  1.265253e-02 -4.218321e-02 -1.436633e+00]
  [-1.299403e-02  9.998849e-01 -7.831284e-03 -8.456208e-01]
  [ 4.207926e-02  8.371815e-03  9.990791e-01  2.559694e+01]
  [ 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00]]]
```

I am doing an ICP in each point cloud I have and then I am taking the transformation matrix of each source and target, and making my array trajectory. but I see that the ground truth has only the first matrix equaling 1 and the rest all starts with 9 and mine is jumping from 1 to 9 all the time

```
[[[ 9.99990294e-01 -9.79876725e-04  4.74431620e-04 -6.63781000e-03]
  [ 9.79861234e-04  9.99990406e-01  3.28838706e-05  5.59895312e-03]
  [-4.74463614e-04 -3.24189697e-05  9.99990774e-01 -1.14888461e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00018268e+00  8.14803903e-04 -4.53000232e-04 -1.68058379e-02]
  [-8.14816032e-04  1.00018278e+00 -2.65962366e-05 -4.41518765e-04]
  [ 4.52978415e-04  2.69652693e-05  1.00018301e+00 -4.50599907e-04]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.99845226e-01 -1.98113875e-05  2.74619394e-04 -8.50417373e-03]
  [ 1.96509057e-05  9.99845093e-01  5.84279054e-04 -8.79387604e-04]
  [-2.74630925e-04 -5.84273635e-04  9.99845056e-01  1.79846462e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.99844965e-01  2.57145746e-04  4.18682639e-04 -5.36429085e-03]
  [-2.57644879e-04  9.99844341e-01  1.19234806e-03 -1.11984018e-03]
  [-4.18375673e-04 -1.19245580e-03  9.99844287e-01  3.66727746e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00038202e+00  2.76087779e-04  3.37802144e-04 -6.13155960e-03]
  [-2.76256937e-04  1.00038195e+00  5.01007154e-04 -2.43701146e-03]
  [-3.37663819e-04 -5.01100391e-04  1.00038193e+00  1.72724107e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00051256e+00  1.30503950e-04 -5.23983383e-04 -5.60173718e-03]
  [-1.31065989e-04  1.00051212e+00 -1.07328758e-03 -8.35482833e-03]
  [ 5.23843081e-04  1.07335606e-03  1.00051200e+00 -2.18030897e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00031491e+00  3.05967105e-04 -1.13032591e-04 -2.91990007e-03]
  [-3.05962652e-04  1.00031491e+00  3.94262340e-05 -2.74101180e-03]
  [ 1.13044645e-04 -3.93916590e-05  1.00031495e+00  4.71574420e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00038083e+00  3.12874119e-04  2.04488306e-04  2.03103468e-03]
  [-3.12926920e-04  1.00038082e+00  2.58326907e-04 -1.32311207e-03]
  [-2.04407496e-04 -2.58390855e-04  1.00038085e+00  9.50509109e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.99996307e-01  3.16230221e-04  3.55686815e-04  1.56106875e-03]
  [-3.15987809e-04  9.99996139e-01 -6.81380268e-04 -7.12932823e-03]
  [-3.55902189e-04  6.81267797e-04  9.99996125e-01  4.87799679e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00030792e+00 -1.46242291e-04  3.49406989e-04  9.69184039e-04]
  [ 1.46417012e-04  1.00030785e+00 -5.00232419e-04 -3.23758223e-03]
  [-3.49333809e-04  5.00283527e-04  1.00030780e+00  1.19268204e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00069025e+00  9.45843059e-05 -1.91183889e-04  2.31457942e-03]
  [-9.46790008e-05  1.00069015e+00 -4.95701874e-04 -1.87684101e-03]
  [ 1.91137011e-04  4.95719951e-04  1.00069014e+00 -2.58417438e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00086013e+00  8.82705138e-05  7.90657503e-04  2.97173553e-03]
  [-8.90159236e-05  1.00085999e+00  9.43597733e-04  8.45910549e-04]
  [-7.90573928e-04 -9.43667756e-04  1.00085968e+00  1.96582634e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00076542e+00 -9.02622141e-05  1.41725256e-03  4.94193135e-03]
  [ 9.01544875e-05  1.00076642e+00  7.61327929e-05  9.95342927e-04]
  [-1.41725941e-03 -7.60050425e-05  1.00076542e+00 -5.16527873e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00126338e+00  1.14192275e-04  6.66747484e-04  3.31178934e-03]
  [-1.14418718e-04  1.00126354e+00  3.40024696e-04  1.40844775e-03]
  [-6.66708662e-04 -3.40100811e-04  1.00126333e+00 -9.41134558e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00069822e+00 -1.73396713e-04 -1.15113528e-04  3.91673690e-03]
  [ 1.73260997e-04  1.00069753e+00 -1.17876314e-03 -2.32975542e-03]
  [ 1.15317698e-04  1.17874318e-03  1.00069754e+00 -3.15845440e-02]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00096536e+00  2.05189631e-05  9.53534802e-05  1.49264147e-03]
  [-2.05062720e-05  1.00096536e+00 -1.33221933e-04 -2.56480487e-03]
  [-9.53562103e-05  1.33219979e-04  1.00096536e+00 -3.24515831e-02]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00127178e+00 -2.55537143e-05  5.35495618e-04  1.03115070e-03]
  [ 2.61570837e-05  1.00127129e+00 -1.12820602e-03 -2.32347878e-03]
  [-5.35466485e-04  1.12821985e-03  1.00127115e+00 -4.01131776e-02]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00038527e+00  3.83049348e-04 -4.13311775e-04  2.34035456e-03]
  [-3.83805707e-04  1.00038367e+00 -1.83217834e-03 -6.41354056e-03]
  [ 4.12609507e-04  1.83233662e-03  1.00038366e+00 -3.48101996e-02]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00057952e+00  2.91010353e-04 -9.78183854e-04  4.34165320e-03]
  [-2.90557322e-04  1.00057989e+00  4.63514314e-04  6.86065524e-04]
  [ 9.78318517e-04 -4.63230019e-04  1.00057946e+00 -1.38228691e-02]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00048248e+00 -1.45027908e-04 -1.73677969e-03  1.32524672e-03]
  [ 1.47115248e-04  1.00048326e+00  1.20235915e-03  1.09147387e-03]
  [ 1.73660412e-03 -1.20261271e-03  1.00048177e+00 -1.29471686e-02]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00032461e+00  1.80959529e-04 -1.87998946e-03 -1.91349808e-03]
  [-1.78325431e-04  1.00032539e+00  1.40165445e-03  2.24994895e-04]
  [ 1.88024115e-03 -1.40131681e-03  1.00032364e+00 -2.52663491e-02]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00113679e+00 -1.78816598e-04 -1.86672384e-03 -8.09504432e-03]
  [ 1.83125725e-04  1.00113586e+00  2.31110326e-03 -9.76751278e-04]
  [ 1.86630604e-03 -2.31144066e-03  1.00113414e+00 -3.33325648e-02]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.99165338e-01 -2.53744146e-04 -2.34676360e-03 -4.83436625e-03]
  [ 2.73346882e-04  9.99133201e-01  8.34959634e-03  1.25203668e-02]
  [ 2.34456115e-03 -8.35021506e-03  9.99130483e-01 -9.87975894e-04]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.99698005e-01 -2.16002642e-04 -1.63954977e-03 -7.91466922e-03]
  [ 2.21958657e-04  9.99692749e-01  3.63230921e-03  4.09689059e-03]
  [ 1.63875408e-03 -3.63266827e-03  9.99691429e-01 -6.86969604e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.99156645e-01 -3.14720080e-04 -1.28916127e-03 -1.88186353e-03]
  [ 3.19916225e-04  9.99149351e-01  4.02902138e-03  5.14401403e-03]
  [ 1.28788164e-03 -4.02943060e-03  9.99148571e-01 -8.60493541e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00023543e+00 -6.24236501e-04 -1.26204086e-03  4.49581779e-03]
  [ 6.31451535e-04  1.00021983e+00  5.72601936e-03  6.96306821e-03]
  [ 1.25844639e-03 -5.72681042e-03  1.00021924e+00  8.21701639e-04]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 9.99924665e-01  1.35111793e-04 -8.15275284e-04  4.49949924e-03]
  [-1.31882380e-04  9.99917158e-01  3.95958893e-03  5.75866825e-03]
  [ 8.15803913e-04 -3.95948005e-03  9.99916834e-01 -4.43610552e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00001794e+00  4.96205589e-04 -5.98112845e-05 -1.23280619e-03]
  [-4.96172402e-04  1.00001779e+00  5.53613659e-04 -2.56423656e-04]
  [ 6.00859692e-05 -5.53583914e-04  1.00001791e+00  1.49347691e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.00083213e+00  3.53418101e-04  2.19645127e-05  8.16955085e-04]
  [-3.53417764e-04  1.00083213e+00 -1.53434743e-05 -3.27813758e-03]
  [-2.19699295e-05  1.53357172e-05  1.00083219e+00  1.74476531e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]]
```

I think my iterations are wrong... I don't know what is doing this to become wrong. If I pass the ICP in source0, source1 I get first matrix. Source1 and source2, I get second matrix. That's what I am doing.

```
# carrega os cloud_points presentes em um arquivo
def load_points(path):
    point_clouds = []
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        points = trimesh.load(filepath).vertices
        point_clouds.append(points)
        # retorna todos os pontos do espaço 3d em um array
        all_points = np.concatenate(point_clouds, axis=0)
    return all_points


def correspondence(source, target, limit):
    # Cria uma árvore KD a partir da origem
    # para encontrar o ponto mais próximo na source ate prox ponto
    kd_source = cKDTree(source)
    correspondences = []
    for i, points in enumerate(target):# itera sobre os pontos
        d, source_index = kd_source.query(points, k=1) # procura o ponto mais proximo da origem ate esse
        if(d < limit): 
            correspondences.append((source_index, i))
    return correspondences

def transform(X, Y):
   
    X_ = X - np.mean(X, axis=0)
    Y_ = Y - np.mean(Y, axis=0)

    covariance = np.dot(X_.T, Y_)

    U, _, Vt = np.linalg.svd(covariance)
    R = np.dot(U, Vt)

    scale = np.trace(np.dot(np.dot(R.T, covariance), R)) / np.trace(np.dot(X_.T, X_))

    translation = np.mean(Y, axis=0) - scale * np.dot(R, np.mean(X, axis=0))

    transformation_matrix = np.eye(4)
    # parte superior esquerda (rotação e escala)
    transformation_matrix[:3, :3] = scale * R
    # coluna da direita (translação)
    transformation_matrix[:3, 3] = translation

    return transformation_matrix



# (Iterative Closest-Points (ICP))
def estimate_transform(source, target, correspondences, limit):
    arr = np.array(correspondences) # pega todas as correspondencias de todos os pontos
    length = arr.shape[0]

  
    source_p = source[arr[:, 0]]
    target_p = target[arr[:, 1]]

   
    iterations = 1000
    limit = 0.1  
    best_inliers = None
    best_transform = None

    for i in range(iterations):
        # escolhe entre 3 para estimar a matriz de transformação
        index = np.random.choice(length, size=3, replace=False)
        src_sample = source_p[index]
        trg_sample = target_p[index]

        # matriz de transformação em cada amostras
        matrix = transform(src_sample, trg_sample)

        # Modern Robotics, Chapter 3.3.1: Homogeneous Transformation Matrices
        # transformacao dos pontos
        h_p = np.column_stack((source_p, np.ones(len(source_p)))) #homogenous points
        t_p = np.dot(h_p, matrix.T) #transform points multiplicado pela matriz trasnposta

        
        d = np.linalg.norm(target_p - t_p[:, :3], axis=1)

        
        inliers = np.where(d < limit)[0]

        
        if best_inliers is None or len(inliers) > len(best_inliers):
            best_inliers = inliers
            best_transform = matrix #transform

    
    best_src_points = source_p[best_inliers]
    best_dst_points = target_p[best_inliers]
    best_transform = transform(best_src_points, best_dst_points) #matrix

    return best_transform
```

```
trajectory = []

#carrega os dados do arquivo
DIR = '/content/drive/MyDrive/LIDAR/KITTI-Sequence'

subDIR = sorted(os.listdir(DIR))
for i, DIRs in enumerate(subDIR[:-1]):  # iterar as subpastas target
    source = os.path.join(DIR, DIRs) #começa a partir do primeiro
    target = os.path.join(DIR, subDIR[i + 1])

    X = load_points(source)
    Y = load_points(target)

    correspondences = correspondence(X, Y, 0.1)

    transform_matrix = estimate_transform(X, Y, correspondences, 0.1)

    Y_aligned = np.dot(np.column_stack((Y, np.ones(len(Y)))), transform_matrix.T)[:, :3]


    # final trajectory
    trajectory.append(transform_matrix)
final_trajectory = np.array(trajectory)
```

Comment: Hi. Would you please consider writing a synthesis of your problem? You posted a lot of numbers and a lot of code but it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Stef Hello, of course! I need to estimate the trajectory of a car, by 30 point clouds. I have 30 .obj files and need to take the transformation matrix of each of them, and finally make an array with all of them to get the trajectory of the car. I need to use iterative closest points. But they gave me an 30 matrix ground truth and mine is giving 29 matrix because de ICP uses pairs of point clouds. Mine looks too different and I am afraid I am doing something wrong in my code. The numbers are homogeneous coordinates transformation matrices

Comment: Do you need to use ICP at all for this? It sounds like you could just calculate the centre of mass of each point cloud, and the resulting 30 points are your trajectory